# Polish/ Russian Town - 1913

Tags: russia, historical-gazetteer, 1910s

Grandmother & Father immigrated from Russia/Poland in 1913, from listed
location of Jesnayewa, Russia/Poland. have not been able thus far to find
this town/city to further advance information of family roots! Traveled
under the name Kloc...to New York...finally to Shamokin, Pa.

Comment: It would help greatly to provide a scan of the document where you found this name. I don't see any polish citty with a similar name, also a A followed by a Y is almost impossible in polish language so there's definitely a misspelling.

Comment: Yesnayewa is not likely correct spelling, but YA graphem is not meaningless, because there is a lot of villages which names are derived from the name of tree YASEN'  https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ясень or Fraxinus

Comment: Maybe we are talinkg about https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesionowo,_Braniewo_County

Comment: jesnayewa was listed as Father's birthplace in passenger list of the ship Potsdam departed Rotterdam 29 may, 1913. Also,  surname Kloc found

Answer (score 3):

My favorite site for finding place names in Russia and Europe is geonames. "http://www.geonames.org/advanced-search.html?"

Use the advanced search with the "fuzzy" search selected -- I've found it will present me with a result that includes the placename that I'm looking for.

In this case I didn't find any options for "Jesnayewa" but when using the "Y" variation I got the following results:
[image]

Take a look at each of these places and see if they may be located in an area that is familiar.